# Spring Security Oauth 2 custom token end point url

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

Hello I have to integrate spring security oauth2 in my project. So I added the configuration related part and its working fine. But the problem is that the first request for token goes to "/oauth/token"  and I want to change it to "api/v1/token" .
I searched for that and find some solution like adding `token-endpoint-url` in `oauth:authorization-server` also adding custom filter class that will override `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` and passing the url to constructor. But these didn't worked . 
I am getting following error for request to "api/v1/token"-

> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

My configuration is mainly xml based .
Spring-security.xml file-

```
<http pattern="/api/v1/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/v1/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <custom-filter ref="customClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
<http pattern="/test/**" create-session="never"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"       
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
    <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</beans:bean>


 <beans:bean id="customClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            class="com.walletdoc.oauth.web.security.CustomClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
     <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="com.walletdoc.oauth.web.security.SpringSecurityClientService">
    <beans:property name="id" value="mysupplycompany" />
    <beans:property name="secretKey" value="mycompanykey" />
    <beans:property name="authorities" value="ROLE_CLIENT" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</beans:bean>



<authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager" 
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider  ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
            class="com.walletdoc.oauth.web.security.ClientAuthenticationProvider">
</beans:bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" token-endpoint-url="/api/v1/token">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<beans:bean id="tokenStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<beans:bean id="tokenServices"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="3600"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have been trying to solve this issue from last 2 days ,so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working. One thing that was missing in this question was 
`<beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/api/v1/token" />`
in `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` Bean definition.

In the `custom-filter` tag there is reference of `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` Bean and in that Bean one property is defined that id `filterProcessesUrl` and the value is given as the desired url,as in my case it is `/api/v1/token`. And this solves the problem.

So basically for changing token-endpoint-url,we need to change at 4 place-

1. Adding `token-endpoint-url` in `authorization-server` definition
2. Change at `<http pattern="changed URL"`
3. Change at `<intercept-url pattern="changed URL"`
4. And, adding `filterProcessesUrl` property with `value="changed url"` in `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` .

Answer (score 10):

Isn't the path "/oauth/token" kind of a defacto standard ?

Unfortunately I don't have the exact answer for XML configuration but maybe this Java config can give you hints.

When you extend `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` the following method gives you access to a Builder giving access to authorization server configuration :

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer

        // Here you can override the default endpoints mappings
        .pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", "/api/v1/authorize")
        .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/v1/token")

        // .. rest of the authorization server customization
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore);
}
```

It is kind of weird because you override the mappings through a Map, you have to know each path you want to override, and there is not really any hint or documentation in the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` class.

In the end it works, as when the authorization server starts the logs show :

```
...
.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/v1/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto ...
.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/v1/token],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto ...
```

...

I guess in XML it should translate to some element inside `<oauth:authorization-server>` like :

```
<oauth:authorization-server>
  <!-- ... -->
  <pathMappings>
    <!-- key/value here -->
  </pathMappings>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

---

**EDIT :** After checking the [XML schema](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/oauth2/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd), you probably had it right at first, as the `token-endpoint-url` element should have done the math according to the comments :

```
        <xs:attribute name="token-endpoint-url" type="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    The URL at which a request for an access token
                    will be serviced.
                    Default value: "/oauth/token"
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
```

Maybe you should file an issue in the [spring-security-oauth issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues) ?

Comment: Too bad, you should probably file the issue on Spring's issue tracker. In the meanwhile, maybe you can use Java @Configuration instead of XML since it works. Good luck :)

Comment: *"Isn't the path "/oauth/token" kind of a defacto standard ?"* According to the [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749), the endpoints are **not** prefixed with `/oauth`. They are simply `/authorize` and `/token`. So it's probably not a bad idea to change these in the Spring config.